# Count positive values

Tags: list, haskell

Here is my function. It checks for positive values, changes them to ones and sums them.

```
countPositive :: [Integer] -> Integer
countPositive xs = foldr (+) 0 $ map (^0) (filter (>0) xs)
```

Is there a better strategy to count positive values without using `length` but just `foldr`, `map` and `filter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just directly count them with `foldr`:

```
countPositive = foldr (\n count -> if n > 0 then count + 1 else count) 0
```

Or reimplement `length` with `foldr`:

```
countPositive = foldr (const succ) 0 . filter (>0)
```

Comment: can you explain const succ ?

Comment: `const succ = \a -> succ = \a n -> succ n = \a n -> n + 1`. It ignores the elements of the list (the first argument) and just keeps incrementing the counter (the second argument).

Answer (score 10):

Foldr doesn't seem right here.  You want foldl' instead.  This is my solution:

```
countPos :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
countPos = length . filter (> 0)
```

As you don't want to use `length` for some reason you would basically just reinvent it:

```
countPos xs = sum (1 <$ filter (> 0) xs)
```

or yet another method:

```
countPos = foldl' (\x _ -> succ x) 0 . filter (> 0)
```

There are lots and lots of way to do this.  If 100 people answer to this post, chances are you get 100 different ways to do it, but the simplest way is to use `filter` and `length`.